# Deploy a Salesforce Flow from one environment to another using Metadata API

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api

I am unable to move my latest version of a flow to another environment. The latest version is number 29.

When I use this command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Flow:My_Flow-29" -u dev
```

I get the this response:

```
=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME                                 TYPE         PROJECT PATH
────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
My_Flow                                 Flow         force-app/main/default/flows/My_Flow.flow-meta.xml
```

When I try to deploy I use this command:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m "Flow:My_Flow-29" -u staging
```

I get the following response:

```
=== Deployed Source
No results found
```

If I try the same above but **without specifying the version number** (i.e. `sfdx force:source:deploy -m "Flow:My_Flow"`) I am then able to retrieve, but when I deploy I get the following error:

> Invalid version number: 26

```
TYPE   PROJECT PATH                                                                    PROBLEM
─────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────
Error  force-app/main/default/flowDefinitions/My_Flow.flowDefinition-meta.xml        Invalid version number: 26
```

How do I use the metadata API to upload the latest version of my flow?

Comment: Remove the `<activeVersionNumber></activeVersionNumber>` tag from the flowDefinition file and try deploying again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe since API version 44 you can just remove all flow definition files from the folder and from package file and Flows get deployed with incremental versions for each env